# How to convert const uint8_t * const to bool

Tags: c, pointers, type-conversion, boolean

```
const uint8_t * const val;
int num = 5;
const bool res = (val && (num>0));
```

Here, I need to convert a pointer of the type const `uint8_t* const` to `bool`. 
How can/should I do that?

Comment: `val` is a constant pointer, so you must initialize it (make it point somewhere) when you define the variable. Once you have done that, all pointers are implicitly convertible to a boolean value, with only a null pointer being false. So what you have (with the exception of you missing the pointer initialization) will work as you expect (I think).

Comment: The common interpretation of a pointer in a Boolean context is to ask "does the pointer point at something? (true) or is it a null pointer (false)?". Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem:

```
const uint8_t * const val;
```

its a `const` pointer to a `const uint8_t`, so either you have to make it point to some valid memory, typically a `const` variable/value, or get rid of `const`ness.

With warnings enabled, the compiler would have generated a warning on this statement:

```
const bool res = (val && (num>0));
```

because, `val` wasn't initialized. In your case, the Compiler complains here because it is Undefined Behavior. But, I get that the question is not about why or how is it a case of Undefined Behavior, so lets not get into that.

See the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8_t; // There are better ways of doing it, but I am lazy right now
typedef enum { TRUE = 1, FALSE = 0 } Bool_t; // There are better ways of doing it, but I am lazy right now

int main() {

    const uint8_t ch = 'A'; //0x41

    // Below initialization/assignment is what you missed.
    const uint8_t * const val = &ch;
    int num = 5;
    const Bool_t res = *val + num;
    //The above assignment is not suited in terms of accuracy because, 
    //`res` is type `Bool_t`, so it *should* ideally be assigned 
    //with values either TRUE or FALSE, but anyways, here we go.

    printf("0x%x", res);
}
```

Output:

```
0x46
```

Which is as expected: `'A'` + `0x05` is `0x46`.

Note: You could always make a habit of compiling the code with all the warnings enabled. Take out some spare time and read [this rich documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html). Till then, `-wall` or better yet `-werror` is what you need.

Comment: What's up with the typedefs? These types are included in `stdint.h` and `stdbool.h`.

Comment: I wanted OP to understand that the same is applicable to all data types including user defined ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile your code with warnings enabled, you will get:

```
warning: 'val' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
    const bool res = (val && (num>0));
                     ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

which comes from the fact that you declare you pointer, but you don't initiailze it, here:

```
const uint8_t * const val;
```

Initialize it to a value, like this for example:

```
uint8_t v = 5; // example value
const uint8_t * const val = &v;
```

---

> How to convert `const uint8_t * const` to `bool`?

Regardless of the `const` keywords you have there, you need to focus in the fact that you have a pointer.

All pointers are **implicitly convertible** to a boolean value (thus `bool` too), meaning that you don't have to do something more, your code shall do the trick (now that you initialized `val`).